# srand48 for Int64 in Swift 4?

Tags: swift, srand

I'm creating a random number code generator with Int value as a seed. I used srand48 and drand48, and it worked correctly until I found out my seed value is too big for 32-bit devices.

To cater this, I tried to replace Int with Int64. Problem is, srand48 doesn't take Int64 as a parameter. Do you have any suggestions how to mitigate this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *truncate* `Int64` to `Int`:

```
let i64 = Int64(...)
srand48(Int(truncatingIfNeeded: i64))
```

On a 32-bit device this will truncate the 64-bit number to its least significant 32 bits.

Comment: I just read the documentation in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2926530-init, and turns out it's a great way to to solve this. Thanks for the suggestion, Martin!